# Springboot - Rest call from Scheduled task using Rest template throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am making a Rest call from scheduled task using resttemplate  and I am getting the below exception

Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request. occurred while running scheduled task

Code snippet

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class TestSchdeuledTaskService {

@Autowired
    private TestServiceRestClient testService;

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${scheduler.fixedDelay:60000}")
public void scheduledtask() {

        try {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("testscheduledtask");
            testService.testRestCall();

            } catch (Exception e) {
             String logError = String.format("Exception %s occurred while running scheduled task ", e);
            log.error(logError);
        }
    }
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class TestServiceRestClient{


    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;


    public void testRestCall() {

        log.debug("Get call testing");
        int min = 1;
        int max = 500;
        Random r = new Random();
        int id = r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        Comment comment = restTemplate.getForObject("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/" + id, Comment.class);
        log.debug(comment.toString());

    }   

}
```

Any pointer on why this exception is happening. Thanks

Comment: Care to share the code snippet that is throwing the exception?

Comment: added the code snippet. thanks for looking